# Subtracting hours from os.date()

Tags: lua

I currently have this code

```
local day = os.date('%A')
local timesubtract = 8 --GMT -8 hours
local hour = os.date('%H')
local newtime = (day-timesubtract)
```

Obviously it doesnt work. I've been sifting through posts on forums for the past 3-4 hours with no luck

Basically, I need to call the day of the week for a specific timezone. For example today is Saturday, however somewhere else in the world it could possibly be Friday still, and if the offset is set in "timesubtract" it will call the correct day of the week for that timezone.

Comment: `local hour = os.date('!%H')`

Comment: this only subtrracts one hour

Answer (score 5):

You can get the time in seconds (since a specific point in past) with [os.time](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.time), add your offset (in seconds) and format this to a string (or table, whatever you prefer) with [os.date](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date).

```
print(os.date("%c"))    -- Print current time (08/15/15 10:45:55)

local seconds_since_xxx = os.time() -- Get current time in seconds
seconds_since_xxx = seconds_since_xxx - (60 * 60 * 11)  -- Subtract 11 hours from time

print(os.date("%c", seconds_since_xxx)) -- Print calculated time (08/14/15 23:45:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function format_time(timestamp, format, tzoffset, tzname)
  if tzoffset == "local" then  -- calculate local time zone (for the server)
  local now = os.time()
  local local_t = os.date("*t", now)
  local utc_t = os.date("!*t", now)
  local delta = (local_t.hour - utc_t.hour)*60 + (local_t.min - utc_t.min)
  local h, m = math.modf( delta / 60)
  tzoffset = string.format("%+.4d", 100 * h + 60 * m)
end
  tzoffset = tzoffset or "GMT-8"
  format = format:gsub("%%z", tzname or tzoffset)
if tzoffset == "GMT-8" then
  tzoffset = "-0800"
end
tzoffset = tzoffset:gsub(":", "")

local sign = 1
if tzoffset:sub(1,1) == "-" then
  sign = -1
  tzoffset = tzoffset:sub(2)
elseif tzoffset:sub(1,1) == "+" then
  tzoffset = tzoffset:sub(2)
end
tzoffset = sign * (tonumber(tzoffset:sub(1,2))*60 +
tonumber(tzoffset:sub(3,4)))*60
return os.date(format, timestamp + tzoffset)
end

print (format_time(os.time(), "%A"))
```

So It turns out I was under thinking things. This code provides the exact functions I required.

Answer (score 0):

Another much shorter method

```
local offset= 8
function getServerDay()

local timeNow = os.date("*t")
timeNow.day = timeNow.day - 1
local timeYesterday = os.time(timeNow)

return tonumber(os.date("%H")) >= offset and os.date("%A") or os.date("%A", timeYesterday)
end

print(getServerDay())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a library such as [luatz](https://github.com/daurnimator/luatz), it allows you to perform complex date math across differing timezones.